# How to include files outside of Docker's build context?

Tags: docker

How can I include files from outside of Docker's build context using the "ADD" command in the Docker file?

From the Docker documentation:

> The  path must be inside the context of the build; you cannot ADD
>   ../something/something, because the first step of a docker build is to
>   send the context directory (and subdirectories) to the docker daemon.

I do not want to restructure my whole project just to accommodate Docker in this matter. I want to keep all my Docker files in the same sub-directory.

Also, it appears Docker does not yet (and may not ever) support symlinks: [Dockerfile ADD command does not follow symlinks on host #1676.](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/1676)

The only other thing I can think of is to include a pre-build step to copy the files into the Docker build context (and configure my version control to ignore those files). Is there a better workaround for than that?

Comment: This has got to be the worst thing about Docker. From my point of view, there is no such thing as a "Docker project". Docker is for shipping projects. Its just a tool. I don't want to have to rebuild my whole project to accomadte docker, adding .dockerignore etc. At the end of the day, who knows how long Docker will last? It would be great to have a seperation between code (i.e. angular project), and whatever means to deploy it (i.e. docker). After all, there really is no benefit to having a docker file next to everything else. Its just wiring things up in order to create an image :(

Comment: Yeah, this is a big downer.  I'm facing the same issue and I have a larger sized binary file (already compressed) that I don't want to copy into each Docker build context.  I'd rather source it from its current location (outside the Docker build context).  And I don't want to map a volume at run time, because I'm trying to COPY/ADD the file at build-time and unzip and do what I need so certain binaries are baked into the image.  This way spinning up the containers are quick.

Comment: I found a good structure and I explain with details at https://stackoverflow.com/a/53298446/433814

Comment: the problem with docker builds is the made-up concept of "context". Dockerfiles are not sufficient to define a build, unless they are placed under a strategic directory (aka context), i.e. "/" as an extreme, so you can access any path (note that that's not the right thing to do in a sane project either..., plus it makes docker builds very slow because docker scans the entire context at start). You can consider building a docker image with all the required files, and usinng `FROM` to continue from there. I would not change the project structure to accommodate Docker (or any build tools).

Comment: In a newish feature If you have dockerfile 1.4+ and buildx 0.8+ you can do something like this `docker buildx build --build-context othersource= ../something/something .` see answer below

Answer (score 708, accepted):

The best way to work around this is to specify the Dockerfile independently of the build context, using -f.

For instance, this command will give the ADD command access to anything in your current directory.

```
docker build -f docker-files/Dockerfile .
```

**Update**: Docker now allows having the Dockerfile outside the build context (fixed in 18.03.0-ce). So you can also do something like

```
docker build -f ../Dockerfile .
```

Comment: I held off on accepting an answer because I wasn't thrilled with the first two. However, this is a clean and straightforward solution.

Comment: How can I add -f flag on the docker-compose.yml build section ?

Comment: @Ro. you use the `dockerfile:` property in the `build:` section in the Compose file https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/compose-file-reference

Comment: I get "The Dockerfile must be within the build context" - I'd really like to have one Dockerfile that can reside below the current build context. In your example you have the Dockerfile within/below the current build context, which of course, works.

Comment: @AlexanderMills I see your problem. I guess you have some reason for wanting the Dockerfile outside the build context? Is there something you dont want included in the build context? Perhaps .dockerignore (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/dockerignore-file) can help.

Comment: Yeah I just want a shared Dockerfile which corresponds to multiple subdirectories, all of which are "build contexts"

Comment: Does this solve the OP's problem of wanting to `ADD` a file that is outside the context directory? That's what I'm trying to do but I don't think using `-f` makes external files addable.

Comment: This just does not work.`ADD failed: Forbidden path outside the build context: ../webservice/npmkeys ()` using `docker build -f files/Dockerfile`

Comment: @loretoparisi The build context includes your current directory, not parent directories. Just go up one folder before you build and ADD webservice/npmkeys without the ”..”

Comment: This solution really isn't useful if your trying to source the file from a completely different outside the Docker build context.  i.e. suppose your file is under /src/my_large_file.zip and your Docker build context is under /home/user1/mydocker_project.   I don't wan to copy the file over to the Docker build context because its large and I want bake some of its contents into the image so that starting up containers isn't a slow process.

Comment: Can't upvote this enough.. in my docker-compose.yml I have: `build: context: .., dockerfile: dir/Dockerfile`. Now my build context is the parent directory!

Comment: The problem remains though, i.e. a Dockerfile is not sufficient when importing files outside the context. For instance, many IDEs and build tools just take the Dockerfile and execute it.

A better solution would be having a `CONTEXT` key to point to a common parent folder, although Docker really struggles with context folders containing too many files (e.g. see https://github.com/docker/toolbox/issues/613). An even better solution would be adding independent/unrelated directories to the context, all from within Dockerfile.

Comment: I'm running this from a directory with a lot of files and the result is that I'm looking at a message that says `sending build context to Docker deamon` and it appears to copy gigagbytes of data.

Comment: @oarfish Do you really need to run it from that directory then? You can use a .dockerignore file to specify files/subdirectories that you dont need.

Comment: @oarfish I think Docker copies everything inside the build context and sends it to a build daemon — also files not needed for the build, see: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/2745#issuecomment-35318051 *"... a very long and resource intensive Uploading context" stage, which appears to (quite needlessly) copy all of the project directories to a temporary location"*, and the reply: *"the short answer is that the docker client does not parse the Dockerfile. It tgz's the context (current dir and all subdirs) up, passed it all to the server"*

Comment: @Cyberwiz The answer is no - you can run the command from anywhere, like `docker build -f dockerfile_dir/Dockerfile context_directory/`. That is an important point although it seems trivial once you notice.

Comment: @MikeGleasonjrCouturier Your hint worked! It's nice to be able to run `docker-compose build` instead of `docker build`. Thanks!

Comment: Just a very basic thing which might help other beginners: the context of the Dockerfile is in which directory `docker build ...` is started, not where the Dockerfile is saved, when using this solution. You can also check this by using `RUN dir -a ./` to see where the context is.

Comment: Looks like Docker does not allow Dockerfile outside of build context, from docs: "By default the docker build command will look for a Dockerfile at the root of the build context. The -f, --file, option lets you specify the path to an alternative file to use instead. This is useful in cases where the same set of files are used for multiple builds. **The path must be to a file within the build context**."

Comment: Weirdly, elsewhere in the docs:

"Traditionally, the Dockerfile is called Dockerfile and located in the root of the context. You use the -f flag with docker build to point to a Dockerfile anywhere in your file system."

Not sure which is accurate.

Comment: The path of the files mentioned in the Dockerfile must be within and relative to the context passed in the build command. So, it's actually not solving the problem of "including files outside of Docker's build context".

Answer (score 95):

I spent a good time trying to figure out  a good pattern and how to better explain what's going on with this feature support. I realized that the best way to explain it was as follows...

- Dockerfile: Will only see files under its own relative path
- Context: a place in "space" where the files you want to share and your Dockerfile will be copied to

So, with that said, here's an example of the Dockerfile that needs to reuse a file called `start.sh`

## Dockerfile

It will **always** load from its relative path, having the current directory of itself as the **local** reference to the paths you specify.

```
COPY start.sh /runtime/start.sh
```

## Files

Considering this idea, we can think of having multiple copies for the Dockerfiles building specific things, but they all need access to the `start.sh`.

```
./all-services/
   /start.sh
   /service-X/Dockerfile
   /service-Y/Dockerfile
   /service-Z/Dockerfile
./docker-compose.yaml
```

Considering this structure and the files above, here's a docker-compose.yml

## docker-compose.yaml

- In this example, your **shared** context directory is the **runtime** directory.

  - Same mental model here, think that all the files under this directory are moved over to the so-called **context**.
  - Similarly, just specify the Dockerfile that you want to copy to that same directory. You can specify that using `dockerfile`.
- The directory where your main content is located is the actual context to be set.

The `docker-compose.yml` is as follows

```yaml
version: "3.3"
services:
  
  service-A
    build:
      context: ./all-service
      dockerfile: ./service-A/Dockerfile

  service-B
    build:
      context: ./all-service
      dockerfile: ./service-B/Dockerfile

  service-C
    build:
      context: ./all-service
      dockerfile: ./service-C/Dockerfile
```

- `all-service` is set as the context, the shared file `start.sh` is copied there as well the Dockerfile specified by each `dockerfile`.
- Each gets to be built their own way, sharing the start file!

Comment: Your point on Dockerfile is not completly true, as pointed by the accepted answer, if you are in a folder hierarchy `a/b/c`, then yes running `docker build .` in `c` won't allow you to access `../file-in-b`. But, I think the general misundertanding in this (or at least mine was) is that the context is defined by the location stated by the first argument of the build command, not by the location of the Dockerfile. So as stated in the accepted answer: from `a`: `docker build -f a/b/c/Dockerfile . ` means that in the Dockerfile `.` is now the folder `a`

Comment: Quoting from the Dockerfile docs:
paths of files and directories will be interpreted as relative to the source of the context of the build.

Comment: sincere thank you for carefully documenting this, really helpful..

Comment: @RobertSinclair, not a problem buddy! This helps me a lot during dev... I'm glad it helped!!!

Comment: This should be the selected solution for this issue, I never used context in docker build but now I can't work without it! This is the most elegant and useful solution

Comment: @PiniCheyni exactly how I feel :)

Comment: What if I have some files in the `all-service` directory that need to go into every container, and also some other files in the `service-a`, `service-b`, etc. folders that need to go only into the respective container, and the `service-a`, `service-b`, etc. folders are outside the `all-service` directory?

Answer (score 84):

I often find myself utilizing the `--build-arg` option for this purpose. For example after putting the following in the Dockerfile:

```
ARG SSH_KEY
RUN echo "$SSH_KEY" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa
```

You can just do:

```
docker build -t some-app --build-arg SSH_KEY="$(cat ~/file/outside/build/context/id_rsa)" .
```

But note the following warning from the [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg):

**Warning: It is not recommended to use build-time variables for passing secrets like github keys, user credentials etc. Build-time variable values are visible to any user of the image with the docker history command.**

Comment: This is poor advice without a huge warning. From the Docker documentation: "Warning: It is not recommended to use build-time variables for passing secrets like github keys, user credentials etc. Build-time variable values are visible to any user of the image with the docker history command." [1]

In other words, the example given in this example discloses the private SSH key in the docker image. In some contexts, that might be fine.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg

Comment: Finally, to overcome this security issue, you could use techniques like squashing or multistage-builds: https://vsupalov.com/build-docker-image-clone-private-repo-ssh-key/

Comment: This is different from what the OP is looking for. You are just executing cat in your local env and passing the result to `docker build`. This isn't docker itself referencing a key file outside the context area (the OP's issue).

Answer (score 61):

On Linux you can mount other directories instead of symlinking them

```bash
mount --bind olddir newdir
```

See https://superuser.com/questions/842642 for more details.

I don't know if something similar is available for other OSes.
I also tried using Samba to share a folder and remount it into the Docker context which worked as well.

Comment: Only root can bind directories

Comment: Users who can access docker have some sort of root access anyway, since arbitrary docker commands can be used to break the chroot jail (or just mount the required files into the container)

Answer (score 24):

I believe the simpler workaround would be to change the 'context' itself.

So, for example, instead of giving:

```
docker build -t hello-demo-app .
```

which sets the current directory as the context, let's say you wanted the parent directory as the context, just use:

```
docker build -t hello-demo-app ..
```

Comment: I think this breaks .dockerignore :-\

Comment: I gave up on .dockerignore and instead made Makefile managed docker folder that contains only files needed for build context... I only need to call `make build` and it pulls in all files needed if they were updated and then it calls appropriate docker build... I need to do extra work, but it works flawlessly because I'm in full control.

Comment: `.dockerignore` must be in the root directory of the context. If you change the context from `.` to `..`, then you have to move the `.dockerignore` file up one directory.

Answer (score 23):

If you read the discussion in the [issue 2745](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/2745) not only docker may never support symlinks they may never support adding files outside your context. Seems to be a design philosophy that files that go into docker build should explicitly be part of its context or be from a URL where it is presumably deployed too with a fixed version so that the build is repeatable with well known URLs or files shipped with the docker container.

> I prefer to build from a version controlled source - ie docker build
>   -t stuff http://my.git.org/repo - otherwise I'm building from some random place with random files.
>
> fundamentally, no....  -- SvenDowideit, Docker Inc

Just my opinion but I think you should restructure to separate out the code and docker repositories. That way the containers can be generic and pull in any version of the code at run time rather than build time.

Alternatively, use docker as your fundamental code deployment artifact and then you put the dockerfile in the root of the code repository. if you go this route probably makes sense to have a parent docker container for more general system level details and a child container for setup specific to your code.

Comment: Why use docker at all then?

Answer (score 15):

This behavior is given by the context directory that the `docker` or `podman` uses to present the files to the build process.
A nice trick here is by changing the context dir during the building instruction to the full path of the directory, that you want to expose to the daemon.
e.g:

```sh
docker build -t imageName:tag -f /path/to/the/Dockerfile /mysrc/path
```

using `/mysrc/path` instead of `.`*(current directory)*, you'll be using that directory as a context, so any files under it can be seen by the build process.
This example you'll be exposing the entire `/mysrc/path` tree to the docker daemon.
When using this with `docker` the user ID who triggered the build must have **recursively read permissions** to any single directory or file from the context dir.

This can be useful in cases where you have the `/home/user/myCoolProject/Dockerfile`  but want to bring to this container build context, files that aren't in the same directory.

Here is an example of building using context dir, but this time using `podman` instead of `docker`.

Lets take as example, having inside your `Dockerfile` a `COPY` or `ADD`instruction which is copying files from a directory outside of your project, like:

```
FROM myImage:tag
...
...
COPY /opt/externalFile ./
ADD /home/user/AnotherProject/anotherExternalFile ./
...
```

In order to build this, with a container file located in the `/home/user/myCoolProject/Dockerfile`, just do something like:

```
cd /home/user/myCoolProject
podman build -t imageName:tag -f Dockefile /
```

Some known use cases to change the context dir, is when using a container as a toolchain for building your souce code.
e.g:

```sh
podman build --platform linux/s390x -t myimage:mytag -f ./Dockerfile /tmp/mysrc
```

or it can be a path relative, like:

```sh
podman build --platform linux/s390x -t myimage:mytag -f ./Dockerfile ../../
```

Another example using this time a global path:

```
FROM myImage:tag
...
...
COPY externalFile ./
ADD  AnotherProject ./
...
```

*Notice that now the full global path for the `COPY` and `ADD` is omitted in the Dockerfile command layers.*
In this case the `contex dir` must be relative to where the files are, if both `externalFile` and `AnotherProject` are in `/opt` directory then the `context dir` for building it must be:

```
podman build -t imageName:tag -f ./Dockerfile /opt
```

**Note when using `COPY` or `ADD` with context dir in `docker`**:
The `docker` daemon will try to "stream" all the files visible on the context dir tree to the daemon, which can slowdown the build. And requires the user to have recursively permission from the context dir.
This behavior can be more costly specially when using the build through the API. However,with `podman` the build happens instantaneously, without needing recursively permissions, that's because `podman` does not enumerate the entire context dir, and doesn't use a `client/server` architecture as well.
The build for such cases can be way more interesting to use `podman` instead of `docker`, when you face such issues using a different context dir.

Some references:

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/
- https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-build.1.html

Comment: This is dangerous and not advisable. The Docker build context will be your entire machine. For one, sending that entire context to the daemon will take forever. Second, the build process itself can do whatever it wants really. A malicious Dockerfile can connect to remote servers with full filesystem read access. Lastly, your Dockerfile instructions like `ADD` become closely coupled to your machine, requiring full aka absolute paths for everything. They will no longer be portable.

Comment: The point here is to explain the entrypoint and how it works, not judge the best standards. Keep in mind the best is to keep everything self-contained in the same project. However the question is how-to achieve such behavior and demonstrate how the entrypoint works. It will not take forever since there's no enumeration in the daemon to make it happen. The context here is defined in the build by an ID with permission on to, not by a fixed path in the daemon, So malicious Dockefile doesn't make sense here.

Comment: Did you test the snippets of your answer? As a regular user, assuming a Unix OS, you don't even have read permission for all of `/`. It will just error out with permission denied. Running the above as `root` could (?) fix it, but is a *terrible* idea. In any case, I CTRL+C-ed out of the build process I ran for testing after 3GB of `/` had been loaded into the daemon's build context. The above doesn't work for me at all!

Comment: For sure, with both cases, and it works, is not a matter of standard, but is a matter of why the context dir exists. Here, I'm using `/`  as example to illustrate the exposure of it. However I improved the answer to address your concerns here

Comment: Nifty trick, PROVIDED you control the build command and docker files, else naughty devs could lift any file off your build machine  :)

Comment: This is the way. Yeah, passing / as your build context is SUPER sketchy. For most projects, it seems like it's reasonable to do `-f path/to/Dockerfile .` to use the root of the project as the context while keeping your Dockerfiles in some sort of order.

Answer (score 15):

I think as of earlier this year a feature was added in buildx to do just this.

If you have dockerfile 1.4+ and buildx 0.8+ you can do something like this:

```bash
docker buildx build --build-context othersource= ../something/something .
```

Then in your docker file you can use the from command to add the context

```
ADD –-from=othersource . /stuff
```

See [this related post](https://www.docker.com/blog/dockerfiles-now-support-multiple-build-contexts/).

Comment: does this work for directories only? I can't pass a file path with getting error `ERROR: failed to get build context path {/builds/my_file <nil>}: not a directory`

Comment: I actually came here to mention multiple build contexts, it’s a shame I had to scroll so long to find your answer..!

Comment: This feature is broken for `podman` on Windows: github.com/containers/podman/issues/18840

Comment: Great answer. This feature is probably newer than the accepted answer but it is definitely the best way to share artifacts between multiple docker builds.

Answer (score 14):

You can also create a tarball of what the image needs first and use that as your context.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#/tarball-contexts

Comment: Great tip! I discovered you can even feed docker build the tarball as context on stdin: `tar zc /dir1 /dir2 |docker build -`. This was very helpful in my case.

Comment: Also it's possible to source from a local existing tar, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54267763/213871) answer

Answer (score 5):

Using docker-compose, I accomplished this by creating a service that mounts the volumes that I need and committing the image of the container. Then, in the subsequent service, I rely on the previously committed image, which has all of the data stored at mounted locations. You will then have have to copy these files to their ultimate destination, as host mounted directories do not get committed when running a `docker commit` command

> You don't have to use docker-compose to accomplish this, but it makes life a bit easier

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml

version: '3'
  services:
    stage:
      image: alpine
      volumes:
        - /host/machine/path:/tmp/container/path
      command: bash -c "cp -r /tmp/container/path /final/container/path"
    setup:
      image: stage
```

```sh
# setup.sh

# Start "stage" service
docker-compose up stage

# Commit changes to an image named "stage"
docker commit $(docker-compose ps -q stage) stage

# Start setup service off of stage image
docker-compose up setup
```

Comment: Using compose, you can now define multiple contexts using `build.additional_contexts`: https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/pull/307

Answer (score 5):

As is described in **[this](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/2745) GitHub issue** the build actually happens in `/tmp/docker-12345`, so a relative path like `../relative-add/some-file` is relative to `/tmp/docker-12345`. It would thus search for `/tmp/relative-add/some-file`, which is also shown in the error message.*

*It is not allowed to include files from outside the build directory, so this results in the "Forbidden path" message."*

Answer (score 5):

### Create a wrapper docker build shell script that grabs the file then calls `docker build` then removes the file.

a simple solution not mentioned anywhere here from my quick skim:

- have a wrapper script called `docker_build.sh`
- have it create tarballs, copy large files to the current working directory
- call `docker build`
- clean up the tarballs, large files, etc

#### this solution is good because (1.) it doesn't have the security hole from copying in your SSH private key (2.) another solution uses `sudo bind` so that has another security hole there because it requires root permission to do `bind`.

Answer (score 4):

I was personally confused by some answers, so decided to explain it simply.

You should pass the **context**, you have specified in Dockerfile, to docker when
want to create image.

I always select root of project as the **context** in Dockerfile.

so for example if you use **COPY** command like **COPY . .**

first dot(.) is the context and second dot(.) is container working directory

Assuming the **context** is project root, **dot(.)** , and code structure is like this

```
sample-project/
  docker/
    Dockerfile
```

If you want to build image

and your path (the path you run the **docker build** command) is **/full-path/sample-project/**,
you should do this

```
docker build -f docker/Dockerfile .
```

and if your path is **/full-path/sample-project/docker/**,
you should do this

```
docker build -f Dockerfile ../
```

Answer (score 3):

Workaround with links:

`ln path/to/file/outside/context/file_to_copy ./file_to_copy`

On Dockerfile, simply:

`COPY file_to_copy /path/to/file`

Comment: I probably wont use this because this doesn't work with soft links, only hard links

Comment: unknown instruction: LN

Comment: @Sheldeeb `ln` would be used on Unix context, not in the Dockerfile, to create the hard link (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ln_(Unix)). Then treat the link as a regular file. It is not capital "LN".

Comment: this may affect the code base, i.e: override an existing file, or even modify a clean git repo. also you may cannot rename the file, for example you cannot modify package.json if you like to run `npm install` after creating the hard link

Comment: When trying to recursively copy a directory with a soft link.... guess what? Nothing was copied. But look, even if we find a way to copy large amount of data into the image, this is still a problem. It takes ages to build and you end up with giant image file. I gave up for now and just copied it all into the build context so I will still have these delays. I don't want a whole new container and communication just for data that is only loaded into memory.

Answer (score 3):

My workaround for the issue. Looked for elegant solution that I won't need to reinvent every time when I build image, and decided to create the following **build-docker.sh** bash script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Check if a tag argument is provided
if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <tag>"
    exit 1
fi

# Assign the tag argument to a variable
TAG=$1

# Copy the source-code directory
cp -R ../source-code ./temp-source-code

# Run the Docker build command with the specified tag
docker build -t "$TAG" .

# Check if Docker build was successful
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Docker build successful, removing temp-source-code directory..."
    rm -rf ./temp-source-code
else
    echo "Docker build failed, temp-source-code directory not removed."
fi
```

In Dockerfile:

```yaml
# Copy the rest of your application's source code
COPY . .

# Remove the existing symlink
RUN rm -f ./src/source-code

# Copy lambda parser
COPY ./temp-source-code ./src/source-code
```

In summary:

1. Run script with desired image tag
2. It will copy required folder into current directory
3. Will run `docker build ...`
4. will remove copied folder from the current director
5. In Dockerfile just add the line that removes symlink because otherwise your folder won't be copied
6. Run the script and enjoy your life :)

Answer (score 2):

An easy workaround might be to simply mount the volume (using the -v or --mount flag) to the container when you run it and access the files that way.

example:

```
docker run -v /path/to/file/on/host:/desired/path/to/file/in/container/ image_name
```

for more see: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Comment: Note that this only works if the volume is a runtime dependency. For build time dependencies, `docker run` is too late.

Comment: Also mounting volumes copies files to the location you are mounting to in context. This means it doubles up my files. What If I need to mount a volume folder with 100's of scripts? Now my host has double the amount of scripts.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue with a project and some data files that I wasn't able to move inside the repo context for HIPAA reasons. I ended up using 2 Dockerfiles. One builds the main application without the stuff I needed outside the container and publishes that to internal repo. Then a second dockerfile pulls that image and adds the data and creates a new image which is then deployed and never stored anywhere.  Not ideal, but it worked for my purposes of keeping sensitive information out of the repo.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, my Dockerfile is written like a template containing placeholders which I'm replacing with real value using my configuration file.

So I couldn't specify this file directly but pipe it into the docker build like this:

```sh
sed "s/%email_address%/$EMAIL_ADDRESS/;" ./Dockerfile | docker build -t katzda/bookings:latest . -f -;
```

But because of the pipe, the `COPY` command didn't work. But the above way solves it by `-f -` (explicitly saying file not provided). Doing only `-` without the `-f` flag, the context AND the Dockerfile are not provided which is a caveat.

Comment: just an FYI, you could use build-args for that

Comment: This solution, which proposes using "docker build -t <tag> . -f -" also solved the problem that I had where I wanted to generate a dockerfile by bash script and input it via STDIN, but I also wanted to COPY files from the local context "."

Answer (score 1):

### How to share *typescript* code between two Dockerfiles

I had this same problem, but for sharing files between two *typescript* projects. Some of the other answers didn't work for me because I needed to preserve the relative import paths between the shared code. I solved it by organizing my code like this:

```
api/
  Dockerfile
  src/
    models/
      index.ts

frontend/
  Dockerfile
  src/
    models/
      index.ts

shared/
  model1.ts
  model2.ts
  index.ts

.dockerignore
```

**Note**: After extracting the shared code into that top folder, I avoided needing to update the import paths because I updated `api/models/index.ts` and `frontend/models/index.ts` to export from shared: (eg `export * from '../../../shared`)

Since the build context is now one directory higher, I had to make a few additional changes:

1. Update the build command to use the new context:

   `docker build -f Dockerfile ..` (two dots instead of one)
2. Use a single `.dockerignore` at the *top level* to exclude all `node_modules`. (eg `**/node_modules/**`)
3. Prefix the `Dockerfile` `COPY` commands with `api/` or `frontend/`
4. Copy `shared` (in addition to `api/src` or `frontend/src`)

   ```
   WORKDIR /usr/src/app

   COPY api/package*.json ./     <---- Prefix with api/
   RUN npm ci

   COPY api/src api/ts*.json ./  <---- Prefix with api/
   COPY shared usr/src/shared    <---- ADDED
   RUN npm run build
   ```

This was the easiest way I could send everything to docker, while preserving the relative import paths in both projects. The tricky (annoying) part was all the  changes/consequences caused by the build context being up one directory.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the build context is the way to go.

If you have a .net core project and you still want to use the Visual Studio UI to debug/publish the project with docker than you can change the context by adding the "DockerfileContext" to your projects .csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
    <DockerfileContext>..\..\.</DockerfileContext>
  </PropertyGroup>

  ...

</Project>
```

Do not forget to change the paths in the Dockerfile accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

One quick and dirty way is to set the build context up as many levels as you need - but this can have consequences.
If you're working in a microservices architecture that looks like this:

```
./Code/Repo1
./Code/Repo2
...
```

You can set the build context to the parent `Code` directory and then access everything, but it turns out that  with a large number of repositories, this can result in the build taking a long time.

An example situation could be that another team maintains a database schema in `Repo1` and your team's code in `Repo2` depends on this. You want to dockerise this dependency with some of your own seed data without worrying about schema changes or polluting the other team's repository (depending on what the changes are you may still have to change your seed data scripts of course)
The second approach is hacky but gets around the issue of long builds:

Create a sh (or ps1) script in `./Code/Repo2` to copy the files you need and invoke the docker commands you want, for example:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
rm -r ./db/schema
mkdir ./db/schema

cp  -r ../Repo1/db/schema ./db/schema

docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml down
docker container prune -f
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up --build
```

In the docker-compose file, simply set the context as `Repo2` root and use the content of the `./db/schema` directory in your dockerfile without worrying about the path.
Bear in mind that you will run the risk of accidentally committing this directory to source control, but scripting cleanup actions should be easy enough.