# How to access files outside of docker-compose build context?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a docker-compose file that has the following services in it:

```
service1:
    privileged: true
    image: storjlabs/billing
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: ../../service1/dockerfiles/service1-development.dockerfile
service2:
    privileged: true
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: ./dockerfiles/service2-development.dockerfile
```

**Is there a way to access files outside of the docker context?**

If I try it now, I get an error that says `ERROR: Forbidden path outside the build context` and spits out the file path. I know I can edit the context to get this to work, but that feels wrong to do and I'm worried about far reaching consequences that might have in our build process.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include files outside of Docker's build context?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27068596/how-to-include-files-outside-of-dockers-build-context)

Comment: This is a docker limitation. bind mounts, hardlinks and increasing your build context are the common solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker now allows having the Dockerfile outside the build context (fixed in 18.03.0-ce, https://github.com/docker/cli/pull/886). So you can also do something like

```
docker build -f ./Dockerfile ../context
```