# Can we build a docker image using .tar or zip archive

Tags: docker, docker-image, docker-build, docker-api

Can we build a docker image using tarball  or zip archive which includes dockerfile inside that. I need to build a image from archives by using docker api.

Is there any reference or resource , I have search for 3o minutes but couldn't find anything.

Help me, please!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

yes a dockerimage can be build from a tarball containing the `Dockerfile`.
Let's assume we have a dockerfile called `myDockerfile` which contains the following scripts

```
FROM ubuntu

COPY ./venv /

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

`myDockerFile` is present inside the folder `dockerfiles`

```
FOLDER --> dockerfiles
FILE   -----------> myDockerFile
```

the tarball for folder `dockerfiles` is called `dockerfiles.tar`

the docker command to build the image will be:-

```
cat dockerfiles.tar | docker build - -f dockerfiles/myDockerFile -t mydockerimage
```

note:-

```
-f denotes the docker file in context to the tarball , if the dockerfile is called 'Dockerfile'
then there is no need to mention the name of the filename verbose
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `docker load` command to get more information [visit](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean, that your tar.gz is containing a Dockerfile and you would like to build the image of it? As it is if you download a archive from a github release, for example: https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/releases?

Yes you can:

```
#!/bin/bash
wget "https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/archive/1.13.2.tar.gz"
tar xvf 1.13.2.tar.gz --strip-components 3 docker-nginx-1.13.2/stable/alpine/Dockerfile && docker build . -t mynginx
```

Comment: actually I was trying to build docker image using a tar which uploads by user on my django app and include dockerfile, bu it return `invalid tar header` error.