# Docker: adding rsa keys to image from outside of build context

Tags: docker, rsa, dockerfile

So I want to include an rsa key in my image so I can clone a git repo into my image when its building. But I really don't want to have to keep this key in the docker build repo. Does anyone have a good recommendation on how to handle this? From the docker documentation and various other threads it seems that there is no way to `COPY` files from outside of the build context. Apart from the following solutions that I am not interested in using:

[How to include files outside of Docker's build context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27068596/how-to-include-files-outside-of-dockers-build-context)

Is there a better solution to this? Or am I going to have to either keep the key in the build repo or build from the location of the of the rsa key I want to use?

I guess a possible way to do it would be to gitignore the key from the build repo and just put it in whenever I clone it, and make a note of it in the readme so other developers know to do this too.

**--- My Solution ---**

I don't think there is a "correct" answer for this but here was the solution I went with.

I create a linux user (somewhere) and generate a key for it. Then create a user on gitlab with only repo cloning rights. I add the public key from the linux user to the gitlab user. Then for the build I create the .ssh folder and copy in the users private key with a config file. I just store that users key in the docker build repo.

build steps:

```
RUN mkdir ~/.ssh
RUN touch ~/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN ssh-keyscan -t rsa gitlab_host > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
COPY ./ssh/config /root/.ssh
COPY ./ssh/id_rsa_app /root/.ssh
RUN chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa_app
```

ssh config file:

```
Host gitlab-app
  HostName gitlab_host
  IdentityFile /root/.ssh/id_rsa_app
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Now the git clone works inside of the build.

Answer (score 5):

What about using a [build argument](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg)?  Do something like this in your Dockerfile:

```
ARG rsakey
RUN test -n "${rsakey}" && { \
      mkdir -p -m 700 /root/.ssh; \
      echo "${rsakey}" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa; \
      chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa; \
    } || :
```

Then, when you build the image, use the `--build-arg` option:

```
docker build -t sshtest --build-arg rsakey="$(cat /path/to/id_rsa)" .
```

This will inject the key into the image at build time without requiring it to live in your build context.

Comment: thanks, this would be a workable solution. but we decided on creating a linux user called 'app', created a key for it and then created an 'app' user on our gitlab with only rights to clone repos. We then just put this key in our docker repos with a config file. see above.

Comment: It's not an ideal solution. The content of the key is appended to the command line executing `docker build`, which might end up in some logs at the end (it happened to us building the docker images with gradle)