# Adding a file from an external absolute location during Docker BUILD?

Tags: docker

I am attempting to modify a `Dockerfile` that includes code like this:

```
ARG FILE_SOURCE_DIR

ADD ${FILE_SOURCE_DIR}/check-md5.sh /download/
ADD ${FILE_SOURCE_DIR}/app /app/
ADD ${FILE_SOURCE_DIR}/R/JRI.jar /download/
ADD ${FILE_SOURCE_DIR}/R/JRIEngine.jar /download/
ADD ${FILE_SOURCE_DIR}/R/REngine.jar /download/
```

My build environment looks like this:

```
   \downloads
   \images
       \kafka
           Dockerfile
```

I would like to pass in `FILE_SOURCE_DIR` as a relative path (per the documentation) but I can't get the syntax right - no matter what I try I get an error similar to:

```
 ADD failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder187920988/downloads/check-md5.sh: no such file or directory
```

Sometimes I get this:

```
ADD failed: Forbidden path outside the build context: ../../downloads/check-md5.sh ()
```

I know that the path has to be **relative** to the context directory but as I said, nothing I try seems to work:

```
"../../downloads"
"..\..\downloads"
"C:\path\downloads\"
```

Is the Docker ADD command limited to things inside the context?   If so, how does one include the same file in multiple contexts?

Comment: Just found this question....
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27068596/how-to-include-files-outside-of-dockers-build-context?rq=1

Comment: It looks like the only way to do this is to add the file from a remote HTTP:// URL.   In our case, we wound up setting up a Tomcat instance and pulling the files from there.   From the documentation:   `If <src> is a URL and <dest> does not end with a trailing slash, then a file is downloaded from the URL and copied to <dest>.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ADD obeys the following rules:
>
> The  path must be inside the context of the build
>   ...

From [Dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add).

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the Dockerfile outside the Kafka folder using -f.

```
docker build -t tag-name -f images/kafka/Dockerfile .
```

So that you can access the download folder