# Access to outside of context in Dockerfile

Tags: java, maven, docker

In my Maven project I have following structure:

```
docker/
   docker-compose.yml
   A/
     Dockerfile
   B/
     Dockerfile
src/
target/
   foo.war
```

In A's Dockerfile I need access to war in `/target` folder with the following command:

```
COPY ../../target/foo.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/foo.war
```

when I run `docker-compose up` tt gives me error

> failed to build: COPY failed: Forbidden path outside the build
>   context: ../../target/foo.war

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  fooA:
    build: ./docker/A
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - fooB

  fooB:
    build: ./docker/fooB
    ports:
      - "5433:5433"
```

Can you tell me how to solve this? I don't want copy war file manually after every project build.

Comment: Are you building with docker-compose or docker build? Your build context should be set to the root of your project. You can set it in docker-compose, or if you run your build from the root of the project, then your target/foo.war should be within the context. It seems to me you are not running the build command from the root directory as active directory. is this correct?

Comment: @Mark I should show my docker-compose ... so I upadted my question and I've added docker-compose. I'm starting my app with docker-compose up

Comment: @DenisStephanov there has been an ongoing issue about this since 2013 at [GitHub](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/2745).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know it's not possible to access things outside out your build context.

You might have some luck by mixing the `dockerfile` directive with the `context` directive in your compose file in the root dir of your project as follows:

```
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: A/Dockerfile
```

You may wish to include  a `.dockerignore` in the project root dir to prevent the entire project being send to the docker daemon resulting in potentially much slower builds.

Answer (score 13):

## Dir Structure

Suppose you have the following dir structure

```
./docker-compose.yaml
./all-runners/
        /start.sh
        /runner-A/Dockerfile
        /runner-B/Dockerfile
        /runner-C/Dockerfile
```

- I  had a requirement where all Dockerfiles share the same file
- The top-level docker-compose is the driver of all the builds

## Dockerfile

It `ALWAYS` will load from its relative path, having the current dir of itself as the `local` reference to the paths you specify.

```
COPY start.sh /runtime/start.sh
```

## Docker-compose

- The real trick is here. The context you want to set is the directory where your main content is located.
- In this example, your `shared` context dir is the `runtime` dir.

  - Imagine all the files under this dir being copied over to a dir called `context`.
  - Now imaging you can just specify the Dockerfile that you want to copy to  that same dir. You can specify that using `dockerfile`.

The `docker-compose.yml` is as follows

```
version: "3.3"
services:

  runner-A
    build:
      context: ./all-runners
      dockerfile: ./runner-A/Dockerfile

  runner-B
    build:
      context: ./all-runners
      dockerfile: ./runner-B/Dockerfile

  runner-C
    build:
      context: ./all-runners
      dockerfile: ./runner-C/Dockerfile
```

- Since the context is set to `all-runners`, the file `start.sh` will be reuse by each individual Dockerfile specified by the path in `dockerfile`.
- You get the same effect as in the parent dir, in a more organized way

**Now your build works with files outside the dir of your `Dockerfile`.** The result is just the same when you do the proper mapping!

Happy Dockering !

Answer (score 4):

You can structure your project to have your Compose file and Dockerfile in directory tree like yours. You need to change your Compose file to support this, like this:

```
build:
                        context: ../
                        dockerfile: docker/A/Dockerfile
```

You can then build this set up with `docker-compose -f docker/docker-compose.yml build`.