# Docker add folder into image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

i've docker file which I run **from my root project** and it working ok
Now I need to add project **from** my local machine to the **image** and I did it like following

```
ADD  ../proj1 /go/src/proj1
```

Now I got error

```
Step 7/16 : ADD  ../proj1 /go/src/proj1
ADD failed: Forbidden path outside the build context: ../proj1 ()
```

How can I overcome this? I dont want to put the `proj1` under my `root project`

all other path's on the docker files are ok

```
FROM golang:alpine as builder
WORKDIR /go/src/rootproj
ADD . /go/src/rootproj
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -ldflags '-extldflags "-static"' -o main .
ADD  ../proj1 /go/src/proj1
```

And to build it I run

```
docker build -t myproj .
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include files outside of Docker's build context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27068596/how-to-include-files-outside-of-dockers-build-context)

Comment: @svsd - I've tried it and it doesnt help...any other idea?

Comment: There's no way out of having a copy of `proj1` inside the build context. Maybe you can include it as a Git submodule so it's not manually copied? Or you could build a separate Docker image out of proj1 and use it as one the base images when building the current project. Depends on what you're actually trying to achieve though.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is taken from [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/2745#issuecomment-28698012) by Sjord...

> The build actually happens in `/tmp/docker-12345`, so a relative path like `../relative-add/some-file` is relative to `/tmp/docker-12345`. It would thus search for `/tmp/relative-add/some-file`, which is also shown in the error message. It is not allowed to include files from outside the build directory, so this results in the "Forbidden path" message.