# docker-compose - ADD failed: Forbidden path outside the build context

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have such folder structure

```
project
    - config
        -docker
           Dockerfile
           docker-compose.yml
    - src
       here_is_code
    requirements.txt
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD ../../requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD src /code/
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ../../
      dockerfile: config/docker/Dockerfile
    command:
        bash -c "ls"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    expose:
      - "8000"
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
    - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
      - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
    - web
```

When I run `docker-compose build` I get following error:

> Service 'web' failed to build: ADD failed: Forbidden path outside the build context: ../../requirements.txt ()

Is it possible to add requirements.txt or I'll have to copy this file into docker directory? Or maybe I need to use any entrypoint (entrypoint.sh)?

**UPDATE**

After `docker build -f config/docker/Dockerfile .` and `docker-compose up` I can't see my code there. Here is the output of `ls -R /code`

```
web_1    | /code:
web_1    | Dockerfile
web_1    | config
web_1    | docker-compose.yml
web_1    | src
web_1    | static
web_1    | 
web_1    | /code/config:
web_1    | nginx
web_1    | 
web_1    | /code/config/nginx:
web_1    | 
web_1    | /code/src:
web_1    | static
web_1    | 
web_1    | /code/src/static:
web_1    | 
web_1    | /code/static:
```

Comment: I think if you have `context: ../../` you no longer mean to point to `ADD ../../requirements` but rather `ADD ./requirements`. Or is this file 2 levels above the context `../../`? That is not allowed, you should move the file.

Comment: @BorisvanKatwijk - right. I've used `ADD ./requirements` and it works

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include files outside of Docker's build context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27068596/how-to-include-files-outside-of-dockers-build-context)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

context

It's all about context. Specify context and dockerfile in your build and you can plant your Dockerfile anywhere. Play a round with it (that's what she said).

I would at least keep the docker-compose.yaml in a root directory.

```
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: dockerfiles/project-one/Dockerfile
```

Comment: This doesn't work if you want to locate the docker-compose.yaml file in the sub-folder as well. If you have one global docker-compose file, that defeats the purpose of having placing the Dockerfile in a sub-folder. You're then required to use that global docker-compose.yaml file for everything, even if you want to describe separate container collections.

Comment: One global docker-compose defeats nothing.

Comment: Most people are running one docker-compose to build their images straight up.

Comment: I run multiple micro-services with their own Dockerfile in their respective sub-directories--using one docker-compose to build all the images, or I run docker-compose build <image> to build specific ones. Depends on the service, script, etc that I am applying. There's no need to have multiple docker-compose files along side Dockerfiles. Nobody needs extra docker-compose yamls with however many lines in each, when you can just one-line it in a script using the same docker-compose.

Comment: So yeah, when it comes to context--as that is what the answer is about! It works perfectly. Even if you want to waste time placing extra files in directories that aren't otherwise needed.

Answer (score 16):

You cannot get outside of build context (which is normally the working directory) of Docker when building an image.

The reason is pretty simple - Docker consists of command line client and daemon, when you call `docker build ...` first thing happening is that your client packs entire folder (build context) into single archive and sends it to daemon together with your `Dockerfile`. Daemon gets an archive and instructions from `Dockerfile` and that means **daemon does not access your local filesystem** when building an image and cannot walk through `../..` references.

What you need to to set the build context to your root folder and specify `Dockerfile` explicitly.

You build command will look like

```
docker build -f config/docker/Dockerfile .
```

And inside `Dockerfile` you have to remember that all paths are relative to the project root.

So finally you come to following compose file:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .  # here changed
      dockerfile: config/docker/Dockerfile
    command: ["bash", "-c", "ls"]
    expose:
      - "8000"
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - web
```

You go to project root and run

```
docker-compose -f config/docker/docker-compose.yml up
```

Comment: In that way, how should last line `ADD . /code/` looks like?

Comment: Where is your code originally? In `src`? Then `ADD src /code/`.

Comment: Guess, I'm doing something wrong. After I run `docker-compose up`, I can't see my code there

Comment: it's an empty folder

Comment: maybe I'm running `docker-compose up` in wrong way? how it must be?

Comment: This just gives me the error `Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: config/docker/Dockerfile`

Comment: A critical aspect of this answer, which was not obvious to me, is that you then change the individual `Dockerfile`s to reflect the `build` context.  So rather than `../blarg`, it's just `blarg`, since it's the build context of the `docker-compose.yml`.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hope, my answer will help somebody (it is based on many GitHub repositories, I have looked though)

I have wrong project structure. If you need to separate docker files and application code, it's better to put the code in any folder (called `app` for example) in the root folder. Docker files should also be in the root folder. Such structure will avoid a lot of problems and it will be easy to use docker/docker-compose

Answer (score 1):

```
_______________________________
deployments/docker-compose.yml:
[...]
service_name:
  build:
      context: ..                           # *That's what you need!*
      dockerfile: build/package/Dockerfile

_________________________
build/package/Dockerfile:
[...]
COPY . .

_____________________
from root of project:

docker-compose -f deployments/docker-compose.yml up
```

And your container will have everything from the root of a project.