# Copying specific files from root directory of docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, content-management-system, microservices

I'm trying to dockerize a multi container application with docker-compose. It is based on micro services, each using on different ports. In the project root have 5 main folders for micro services, namely ***api***, ***user***, ***convo***, ***bot*** and ***dashboard*** each with a **Dockerfile**. I also have a docker-compose.yml file. Along with these, I also have other configurations files and other important folders in the project root. I'm stuck on how to copy these remaining files and folders inside containers. Do I have to copy those to every Dockerfile?

```
-root
  --api/
    ---Dockerfile
    ---/*Other files and folders*/
  --bot/
    ---Dockerfile
    ---/*Other files and folders*/
  --convo/
    ---Dockerfile
    ---/*Other files and folders*/
  --dashboard/
    ---Dockerfile
    ---/*Other files and folders*/
  --user/
    ---Dockerfile
    ---/*Other files and folders*/
  --docker-compose.yml
  -- /*Other files and folders(How do I copy these?)*/
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to include files outside of Docker's build context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27068596/how-to-include-files-outside-of-dockers-build-context)

Comment: Also try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54287298/docker-compose-add-failed-forbidden-path-outside-the-build-context

Comment: @CameronLittle Yeah the second one helped me. I changed the build context and now looks like it works! Thanks.