# How to execute shell script before docker build

Tags: bash, shell, docker, docker-compose

I`d like to know is there good way to move folder/file, which is outside the building context, to
Inside the build context when docker-compose build. 
Is that possible to solve by using  init.sh or startup.sh by using Docker-compose?

When I build this Dockerfile,

```
….
# set assets to inside docker container
COPY ../../frontend/src/assets /var/www/assets
….
```

And I did `docker-compose build`
However I got error  about this

```
Step 19/21 : COPY ../../frontend/src/assets /var/www/assets
ERROR: Service 'test' failed to build: COPY failed: Forbidden path outside the build context: ../../frontend/src/assets ()
```

If I execute  “ cp -rf  ../../frontend/src/assets ./“ before build and change path of folder in Dockerfile, this is no problem,
But if I could,  I want to make this less operation.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34392052/609290

Comment: @DazWilkin Thanks   @DazWilkin Thanks   I'll add `command: bash -c "cp -r ` in docker-compose.yml :)

Comment: I think you'd be better placed running the build from a parent directory of the files you wish to copy and then explicitly specifying the Dockerfile with `--file=` as described in the comments on that question.

Comment: @DazWilkin If it was just one Dockerfile, I’ll do that. But in this time, we have some Dockerfiles and we need to build at specific directory.