# How to use multiple Dockerfiles within a monorepo?

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to set up a Docker development environment on Windows. I have a code directory structure like so:

```
project/
  node-app/
  react-app-1/
  react-app-2/
  shared/
```

`node-app`, `react-app-1` and `react-app-2` all depend upon the code within `shared`. So, I was thinking of having a `Dockerfile` in each of the apps, with something like this:

```
FROM node:10.0

WORKDIR /app
COPY ../ .

WORKDIR /app/node-app
RUN npm install
```

However, that doesn't work - Docker gives me an error saying that it's a `Forbidden path outside the build context: ../`.

What is the best way to resolve this problem? I'm looking at setting up some sort of Docker Compose after I get this sorted (once again for local development), so my ideal solution would keep that in mind.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/ explains how the context works. If you `docker build .` from the `project/` directory you can get the right context, and you have to specify which Dockerfile to select with `-f`/`--file`. You can also set explicit context and file in the compose file `build` section: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include files outside of Docker's build context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27068596/how-to-include-files-outside-of-dockers-build-context)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`COPY ../ .` is invalid because `..` is outside the build context (by default this is the directory from where the `docker build` command is issued).

To fix that, you could build your application from the top directory (`$PWD` = `project/`), thus making all files/directories in that directory available from the build context, and specify the `Dockerfile` you want to use for the build :

```
cd project/ && docker build -t <your_image_name> -f node-app/Dockerfile .
```

or :

```
docker build -t <your_image_name> -f /path/to/project/node-app/Dockerfile /path/to/project/
```

And of course replace `COPY ../ .` by `COPY . .`, since you are now building from the top directory.