# Troubleshoot directory path error in COPY command in docker file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

I am using COPY command in my docker file on top of ubuntu 16.04. I am getting error as no such file or directory eventhough the directory is present. In the below docker file I want to copy the directory "auth" present inside workspace directory to the docker image (at path /home/ubuntu) and then build the image.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update
COPY /home/ubuntu/authentication/workspace   /home/ubuntu
WORKDIR /home/ubuntu/auth
```

Comment: your copying `authentication ` instead of `auth`?

Comment: auth is a directory present inside workspace. I am assuming it should copy that directory to docker image. So inside the docker image the path would look like /home/ubuntu/auth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a Dockerfile `COPY` command can only refer to files under the context - the current location of the Dockerfile, aka `.`
so you have a few options now:

1. if it is possible to copy the /home/ubuntu/authentication/workspace/ directory content to somewhere inside your project before the build (so now it will be included in your Dockerfile context and you can access it via `COPY ./path/to/content /home/ubuntu`) it can be great. but sometimes you dont want it.
2. instead of copying the directory, bind it to your container via a volume:

when you run the container, add a `-v` option:

```
docker run [....] -v /home/ubuntu/authentication/workspace:/home/ubuntu [...]
```

mind that a volume is designed so any change you made inside the container dir(/home/ubuntu) will affect the bound directory on your host side (/home/ubuntu/authentication/workspace) and vice versa.

3. i found a something over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27068596/how-to-include-files-outside-of-dockers-build-context): this guy is forcing the Dockerfile to accept his context- he is sitting inside the /home/ubuntu/authentication/workspace/ directory, and running there

   `docker build . -f /path/to/Dockerfile`

so now inside his Dockerfile he can refer to /home/ubuntu/authentication/workspace as his context (`.`)

Comment: `COPY /home/ubuntu/authentication/workspace/*   /home/ubuntu/`  
`COPY failed: no source files were specified`

Comment: sorry, my bad. fixed now. but if you get a `COPY failed: no source files were specified` error,  it might be because  in your own `/home/ubuntu/authentication/workspace` directory is empty. this worth a check.

Comment: I tried the same command earlier that you wrote above but this also doesn't seem to work. I can clearly see the directory is present inside the workspace by executing ls command.

Comment: you were right. i made some research, hope it will be helpfull now.