# How can I include python module from an outer folder in the docker image?

Tags: python, git, docker, docker-compose

I have 2 services in one git repository written in the python and deployed to the containers with docker-compose and docker. And I wanted to add some authorization with the third party OpenID Connect service. I have written a module to deal with authorization and I desire to use it in every service.
My repository looks like this:

```
services:
    first_service:
        Dockerfile
        docker-compose.yml
        first_service_python_module
    second_service:
        Dockerfile
        docker-compose.yml
        second_service_python_module
    docker-compose.yml
    .git
```

Initially, I wanted my authorization module to be in the 'services' folder but this way I cannot build my Docker images because Docker can't deal with the outer folder without special argument.
But I cannot specify this argument because of docker-compose files.
So I ended up with the next repository structure:

```
services:
    first_service:
        Dockerfile
        docker-compose.yml
        first_service_python_module
        authorization_module
    second_service:
        Dockerfile
        docker-compose.yml
        second_service_python_module
        authorization_module
    docker-compose.yml
    .git
```

Obviously there is a lot of code duplication and it's hard to maintain.

I want to avoid code duplication. But also not to change docker and docker-compose files a lot. How can I do it?

Comment: Would https://stackoverflow.com/a/53298876/6309 help?

Comment: @VonC, it totally resolves my issue. Thank you for your help!
What will be the right action for me considering my question? Should I remove it somehow? Mark as duplicate? Or answer it myself with your link?

Comment: You can close it as duplicate, unless you can write an answer below which *builds* upon that other answer and provide an addition specific to your use case.

Answer (score 0):

```
services:
    first_service:
        Dockerfile
        docker-compose.yml
        first_service_python_module
    second_service:
        Dockerfile
        docker-compose.yml
        second_service_python_module
    service_authorization:
        authorization_module
    docker-compose.yml
    .git
```

So what you can do is, you can relatively import this authorization_module in your other python modules/services.

refer this https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Sorrowfully it won't solve my issue, because I'm not able to access 'service_authorization' from the container created from current Dockerfiles. And also I won't be able to copy the 'service_authorization' folder from the current context.

Comment: can you run this authorization_module as a service in a different docker file ?

Comment: I want to avoid it as much as possible. I think I will follow the answer from @VonC answer in comments to question.