# problem with Dockerfile copy folder error with absolute or relative path

Tags: docker, path, dockerfile

Error when trying to copy folder with absolute path `COPY /src/www/ /usr/share/nginx/html/` in Dockerfile

> Step 3/4 : COPY /src/www/ /usr/share/nginx/html/
>   COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder685852786/src/www: no such file or directory

Error when trying to copy folder with relative path `COPY ../../../src/www/ /usr/share/nginx/html/` in Dockerfile

> Step 3/4 : COPY ../../../src/www/ /usr/share/nginx/html/
>   COPY failed: Forbidden path outside the build context: ../../../src/www/ ()
>   ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

My folders are like this:

```
------docker-compose.yml
|_____.gitlab-ci.yml  
L_______infrastructure
|   L_____docker
|      L______nginx
|         L____Dockerfile
L______src
   L____www
```

[image]

I'm running Dockerfile directly from .gitlab-ci.yml with `docker build --pull -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE" ./infrastructure/docker/nginx/.`

Dockerfile is:

```
FROM nginx:stable
MAINTAINER Salle MPWAR Maintainers
COPY /src/www/ /usr/share/nginx/html/
// or COPY ../../../src/www/ /usr/share/nginx/html/ I tried both
```

I'm missing something with the routes can't make it work with absolute or relative paths.

So as it's explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27068596/how-to-include-files-outside-of-dockers-build-context), I changed the .gitlab-ci.yml command with `docker build --pull -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE" -f ./infrastructure/docker/nginx/Dockerfile .`

And the Dockerfile COPY command with `COPY ./src/www/ /usr/share/nginx/html/`

But it didn't solve my question, as now I have the error:

> Step 3/3 : COPY ../../../src/www /usr/share/nginx/html COPY failed:
>   Forbidden path outside the build context: ../../../src/www () ERROR:
>   Job failed: exit code 1

Comment: I think a good practice will be to keep Dockerfile at the root of your project directory.

Comment: I think so, but I've been forced to place dockerfile at this folder

Comment: From the top level, run `docker build -f ./infrastructure/docker/nginx/Dockerfile .`.  That makes the context directory be the root of your source tree (and `COPY ./src` will be relative to the right place).

Comment: I just tried with your response, but I hget the error:
`Step 3/4 : COPY ./src/www/ /usr/share/nginx/html/
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder674070819/src/www: no such file or directory`