# Multiple Dockerfiles re-using shared library in project

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have the following code structure and I am trying to structure my Dockerfile(s) as to maximize caching and the like.

```
serverfoo/
    Dockerfile
    main.go

serverbar/
    Dockerfile
    main.go

proto/
    Dockerfile
    sharedproto.proto // Generates a sharedproto.pb.go file to be imported.
```

Both `serverfoo` and `serverbar` import the compiled `sharedproto.pb.go` file which I manually regenerate on my workstation. This works fine but now I am attempting to containerize my two servers.

The *Dockerfiles* with my server folders cannot (by default) copy `proto/` content. Ideally I pre-compile the protobufs into a `sharedproto.pb.go` then import a cached version of that file into the two server *Dockerfiles*. The goal is to cache the compiled protobufs until the underlying protos are modified.

I am new to Docker and need some best practice for this type of thing. I want to avoid a root `Dockerfile` in my project's directory that just has code to compile a zillion different servers.

I am open to restructuring my project to some degree.

Comment: Have a look at [multistage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/). Note that you can `COPY from=otherPublishedImage` as explained in the documentation.

Comment: [How to include files outside of Docker's build context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27068596/how-to-include-files-outside-of-dockers-build-context) also discusses this directory layout (using the `docker build -f` option).

Comment: @Zeitounator I don't think this quite accomplishes what I want. That requires independently rebuilding the protos manually and publishing them before building the latest version of a server. I want the build process for the server to auto-rebuild the dependencies (the protos) if necessary.

Comment: @SamuelDavidson There is currently nothing (to my knowledge...) that clearly accomplishes your requirement out of the box with docker only. Separate builds (possibly triggerring each over via CI) or 2 multistage builds having the same first stage are the first solutions that poped out my mind.

Answer (score 0):

> **NOTE**: I suppose your target is to have on the specific server
>   container both the compiled go file ( from specific **main.go** file )
>   and the compiled protocol buffer file ( from shared
>   **sharedproto.proto** file ).

Assuming your files are organized as follow on your workstation:

```
serverfoo/
   Dockerfile
   main.go

serverbar/
   Dockerfile
   main.go

proto/
   Dockerfile
   sharedproto.proto
```

You can structure the specific server Dockerfile using the multistage build as follow ( e.g. serverbar Dockerfile ):

```
#####
# The serverbar Dockerfile
#####

#----
# Compile proto stage
#----
FROM moul/protoc-gen-gotemplate AS protostage
WORKDIR /workspace
# Copy .proto file
COPY proto/sharedproto.proto .
# Compile .pb.go
RUN protoc -I=. --go_out=. sharedproto.proto

#----
# Build stage
#----
FROM golang:1.12.4-alpine3.9 as buildstage
WORKDIR /workspace
COPY serverbar/main.go .
RUN GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o serverbar main.go

#----
# Final stage
#----
FROM alpine:3.7
WORKDIR /home
COPY --from=buildstage workspace/serverbar .
COPY --from=protostage workspace/sharedproto.pb.go .
CMD ["./serverbar"]
```

Using this approach you basically have the following 3 stages:

1. **proto stage**: On the container created on this stage you need to compile the shared protocol buffer source file into the **sharedproto.pb.go** that then will be included on the third final stage. So here you would need to install on the container the **protoc** compiler and the related Go plugin. However, as usual with Docker, you'll find a docker image that already includes your needed tools. For this purpose we can start from the **moul/protoc-gen-gotemplate** docker image.
   Specifically the follow Dockerfile instruction generates the **workspace/sharedproto.pb.go**:

   ```
     RUN protoc -I=. --go_out=. sharedproto.proto
   ```
2. **build stage**: Here you need to compile the server source file into the executable one. Also this will be included on the third final stage. To avoid to install Golang we can start from the **golang:1.12.4-alpine3.9** docker image that already includes all the needed tools.
   Specifically the follow Dockerfile instruction generates the **workspace/serverbar** executable:

   ```
     RUN GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o serverbar main.go
   ```
3. **final stage**: This is the server container that we'll then upload on our Docker registry for test or production where we'll copy the files compiled on the previous two stage with the following commands:

   ```
     COPY --from=buildstage workspace/serverbar .
     COPY --from=protostage workspace/sharedproto.pb.go .
   ```

---

One of the advantages of this solution is that, for each server build, you can cache the compiled protobufs until the underlying protos are modified.

**Example:**
Building first time the **serverbar** container we can note that .proto compilation is performed on a new container with id **92ae211bd27d**:

```
> docker build -f serverbar/Dockerfile .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  10.24kB
Step 1/13 : FROM moul/protoc-gen-gotemplate AS protostage
 ---> 635345fde953
Step 2/13 : WORKDIR /workspace
 ---> Using cache
 ---> de8890a5e775
Step 3/13 : COPY proto/sharedproto.proto .
 ---> 1253fa0576aa
Step 4/13 : RUN protoc -I=. --go_out=. sharedproto.proto
 ---> Running in 8426f5810b98 
Removing intermediate container 8426f5810b98
 ---> 92ae211bd27d <=========================================
Step 5/13 : FROM golang:1.12.4-alpine3.9 as buildstage
 ---> b97a72b8e97d
Step 6/13 : WORKDIR /workspace

....
```

Building then a second time without modifying the sharedproto.proto we can note that container with id **92ae211bd27d** is re-used from cache.

```
> docker build -f serverbar/Dockerfile .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  10.24kB
Step 1/13 : FROM moul/protoc-gen-gotemplate AS protostage
 ---> 635345fde953
Step 2/13 : WORKDIR /workspace
 ---> Using cache
 ---> de8890a5e775
Step 3/13 : COPY proto/sharedproto.proto .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1253fa0576aa
Step 4/13 : RUN protoc -I=. --go_out=. sharedproto.proto
 ---> Using cache <=========================================
 ---> 92ae211bd27d
Step 5/13 : FROM golang:1.12.4-alpine3.9 as buildstage
 ---> b97a72b8e97d

....
```

Comment: So the magic that makes this work is setting the context to the project root? AFAIK if you `cd` into `serverbar/` and run `docker build .` you would not be able to access the protos. So by running `docker build . -f ./serverbar/Dockerfile` you allow a `COPY` from `/protos/...`?

Comment: Correct. However even if you use the "docker build -f" command as the goal indicated on your question is to cache the compiled protobufs until the underlying protos are modified you need also to approach with multistage build in order to avoid to manually pre-compile the protobufs into a sharedproto.pb.go.