# Docker-compose Error cannot locate specified Dockerfile: Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

When I run docker-compose up I am getting following ERROR: cannot locate specified Dockerfile:Dockerfile
here is my docker-compose file:

```
      version: "3"
services:
    player-docker:
        build: ./src/main/java/spring/multiple/mongo/project/player
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
        depends_on:
            - db
    game-docker:
        build: ./src/main/java/spring/multiple/mongo/project/game
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
        depends_on:
            - db
    score-docker:
        build: ./src/main/java/spring/multiple/mongo/project/score
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
        depends_on:
            - db 
    db:
        image: mongo
        volumes:
            - mongodata:/data/db
        ports:
            - "27017:27017"
        restart: always
volumes:
    mongodata:
```

and I have three Dockerfiles each for player service, game service and score service in different locations.
This is my Dockerfile:

```
    FROM openjdk:8
COPY target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar score.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Dspring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://db:27017/","-jar","-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=0.0.0.0", "score.jar"]
```

[image: the error]

Comment: you would need to show your directory structure.

Comment: You told all three services to `build: .`, the current directory.  If the Dockerfiles are in different directories you need to change those `build:` lines to point there.

Comment: @DavidMaze but when I changed build: . to build: "the location of my dockerfile" I had an error after using docker-compose up. the error is: "Service score-docker failed to build: COPY failed:......: no such file or directory

Comment: As suggest by @DavidMaze, you should change the `build: .` to proper folder of Dockerfile for each 3 services. And revise your Dockerfile's `COPY` instruction, you can use relative path like `COPY ../target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar score.jar`

Comment: (Reading through questions like [How to include files outside of Docker's build context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27068596/how-to-include-files-outside-of-dockers-build-context) can be informative, if the images need to share files from a common directory.)

Comment: @Dai I did all these things for my services. but nothing changed and when I use docker-compose up the error is the same as before.  "Service score-docker failed to build: COPY failed:......: no such file or directory I do not know why

Comment: I updated my question and error that i had got. @Dai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should revise your docker-compose file similar to the following:

```
    score-docker:
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: ./src/main/java/spring/multiple/mongo/project/score/Dockerfile
```

The point is, you need include your `target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar score.jar` into the docker build context. Otherwise, the Dockerfile `COPY` instruction will not able to find the file.
(I suppose you have the `targer` folder sibling as `src` folder).