# Docker copy does not copy over changes

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am stuck on a weird problem with docker. I am copying over a local directory to an image. If I make a change to a file in the local directory, it's not being picked up in a new build. I deleted everything via `docker system prune -a` and rebuild which recreates the conda env, but ended up not taking the file changes. Could it be that the dest parent directory `.config` is hidden, so it's somehow not being deleted?
relevant layers:

```
ADD ../.config/MyConfig /home/myself/.config/MyConfig
WORKDIR /home/myself/.config/MyConfig
CMD ["cat", "config.json"]
```

returns

```
{
  "domain_to_info": {
                "hello": {
                        "username": "myself",
                        "password": { "$ref" : ".password.json#/password" }
                }
        }
}
```

however in my `config.json` file locally I've changed it to `password.json#password` without the hidden `.`

Comment: How are you launching the container?  How do you verify that the content is or isn't changed?

Comment: `docker run user:my-project`

Comment: Is that literally what you have in the Dockerfile; `ADD ../.config/...`?  You can't reference files outside the directory tree you name in the `docker build` command (though you should get an error when the file is inaccessible).

Comment: I was under the impression that the `docker build` command builds in the directory you specified, and to move to another directory outside of it has to be through relative path. If you're saying I can't do this, then I am more confused why this file is copied over successfully.

Comment: [How to include files outside of Docker's build context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27068596/how-to-include-files-outside-of-dockers-build-context) describes this further.

Comment: this is useful, thanks