# docker-compose, failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to compute cache key: "/app/package.json" not found: not found

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose, frontend, backend

I have a problem with pathways `docker-compose`, when I try build project with only `docker build`, it works great, but I mustn't use `docker build`, I have to use `docker-compose`. When I use `docker-compose` it returns 2 ERRORS at step 3/5 `=> ERROR [3/5] COPY /app/package.json .`  and at step 5/5 `=> ERROR [5/5] COPY /app .`:

```
PS C:\Users\mamba\Desktop\project-practice> docker-compose -f docker/docker-compose.yml up -d
[+] Building 1.4s (9/9) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                          0.1s 
 => => transferring dockerfile: 31B                                                                                                                           0.0s 
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                             0.1s 
 => => transferring context: 34B                                                                                                                              0.0s 
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:latest                                                                                                1.0s 
 => [1/5] FROM docker.io/library/node@sha256:c3356b2b11ad643852a321308c15d70ca2bc106e40d3ffe7a4879d3588a9d479                                                 0.0s 
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                             0.1s 
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                               0.0s 
 => CACHED [2/5] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                 0.0s 
 => ERROR [3/5] COPY /app/package.json .                                                                                                                      0.0s 
 => CACHED [4/5] RUN npm install                                                                                                                              0.0s 
 => ERROR [5/5] COPY /app .                                                                                                                                   0.0s 
------
 > [3/5] COPY /app/package.json .:
------
------
 > [5/5] COPY /app .:
------
failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to compute cache key: "/app/package.json" not found: not found
```

this is my project structure
http://skrinshoter.ru/s/080721/upY64zwf

this is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node
WORKDIR /app
COPY /app/package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY /app .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

this is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"
services: 
    react-app:
        working_dir: /app
        build: 
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports: 
            - "3000:3000"
        volumes: 
            - ./app/src:/app/src
        environment: 
            - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
        # env_file: 
        #     - ./docker/.env
```

If I move docker-compose.yml upper in structure of files to `project-practice`, it works great, it builds and server starts, but I have to keep structure of folders and files like this.

```
|-project-practice
|-app
|  |...
|-docker
   |...
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like you mounting volumes wrong.
Change your docker-compose configuration from:

```
build: 
     dockerfile: Dockerfile
volumes:
     - ./app/src:/app/src
```

You mounting only the SRC folder, but you need files outside of it. Also you need to add context to your docker file

to:

```
build: 
     context: ../
     dockerfile: /docker/Dockerfile
volumes:
     - ../app:/app
```

The path should be relative to a docker-compose file location.

Also you need to modify Dockerfile:

```
FROM node
WORKDIR /app
COPY /app/package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY /app .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: I tryed to do as you say, but it still same problems :((

Comment: only this changed now
`failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to compute cache key: "/app" not found: not found`

Comment: but `=> ERROR [3/5] COPY /app/package.json .` and `=> ERROR [5/5] COPY /app .` not changed :(

Comment: Yep, got it. You need to modify Dockerfile. ```COPY ../app/package.json .``` and ```COPY ../app .```

Comment: anyway, :((( not working, same thing(
`=> ERROR [3/5] COPY ../app/package.json .` and `=> ERROR [5/5] COPY ../app .`
and `failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to compute cache key: "/app/package.json" not found: not found` :((((((

Comment: Paths in the `COPY` command need to be relative to the `build: { context: }` directory, and can't start with `..`.  See also [How to include files outside of Docker's build context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27068596/how-to-include-files-outside-of-dockers-build-context).

Comment: i also faced issue but in my case node_module folder was present and I just delete it and it worked perfectly and hopefully I will help you too

Comment: adding the point to the nested directory did really fix my issue thanks a lot @f1x0z

Answer (score 0):

Although it is already answered already, for anyone getting this error for a different use case, this error corresponds to DockerFile rather than docker-compose. Check logs to see where this is failing.

Answer (score -1):

So if your yml is nested you need to use `../app/src:/app/src` rather than the `./app/src:/app/src` as that is it's relative location to the yml.

Comment: I tryed do as you say and it not helps :( what am i do wrong?

Comment: i also faced issue but in my case node_module folder was present and I just delete it and it worked perfectly