# Set relative path in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Trying to set relative path to mount files, but it adding to path folder in which he is(compose file).

```
  liquibase:
    image: liquibase/liquibase
    volumes:
      - ./resources/changelog:/liquibase/changelog
    command: --changeLogFile=master.xml --url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/postgres?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false --username=postgres --password=password update
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    networks:
      - my_network
```

With ./ path: app\docker\resources\changelog
here extra folder 'docker', there is docker-compose file.

I expect app\resources\changelog, how I can set correct relative path?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most paths in the `docker-compose.yml` file, including [`volumes:` bind mount locations](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#short-syntax-3), are relative to the Compose file's location.  If you have [multiple Compose files](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#understanding-multiple-compose-files) they are relative to the first one.  Conversely, there's no restriction against using relative paths or `..` to go to a parent directory.

So if your directory layout is

```
app
+-- docker
|   \-- docker-compose.yml
\-- resources
    \-- changelog
```

and from the `app` directory you're running

```sh
docker-compose -f docker/docker-compose.yml up
```

the `volumes:` paths are resolved relative to the Compose file's location, not the current directory, so you can specify

```yaml
volumes:
  - ../resources/changelog:/liquibase/changelog
```

(Within a Dockerfile, the `COPY` directive can only look inside the build context directory, and can't use `..` to step out of it, but that's specific to the image build.  The [usual solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27068596/how-to-include-files-outside-of-dockers-build-context) to this is to specify `build: ..` or something similar in the Compose file so that the build context is the parent of any directory that contains files that need to be included.)