# Dockerize nestjs microservices application

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, nestjs

I am trying to dockerize a microservice-based application. The `api` is built with nestjs and MySQL. The following is the directory structure

```
.
├── docker-compose.yml
├── api
│   ├── src
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   ├── ormconfig.js
│   └── .env
├── payment
│   ├── src
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── package.json
│   └── package-lock.json
├── notifications
│   ├── src
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── package.json
│   └── package-lock.json
└
```

The following is the Dockerfile inside the `api` directory

```
FROM node:12.22.3

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json .

RUN npm install
    
CMD ["npm", "run", "start:dev"]
```

The below is the `docker-compose.yml` file. Please note that the details for payment & notifications are not added yet in the docker-compose file.

```
version: '3.7'

networks:
  server-network:
    driver: bridge

services:
  api:
    image: api
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: api/Dockerfile
    command: npm run start:dev
    volumes:
      - ".:/usr/src/app"
      - "/usr/src/app/node_modules"
    networks:
      - server-network
    ports:
      - '4000:4000'
    depends_on:
      - mysql
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: api_db
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: api
      MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 12345
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    volumes:
      - api_db_db:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - server-network
volumes:
  api_db:
```

Now, when I try to start the application using `docker-compose up` I'm getting the following error.

> no such file or directory, open '/usr/src/app/package.json'

**UPDATE**
Tried removing the volumes and it didn't help too. Also, try to see what is there in the `api` by listing the contents of the directory by running

`docker-compose run api ls /usr/src/app`

and it shows the following contents in the folder

```
node_modules  package-lock.json
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The `volumes:` block replaces the source code in the image with something different from your host system (you could `docker-compose run api ls /usr/src/app` to see what's actually there; since you're bind-mounting the `.` directory I'd guess it's the root directory including the `docker-compose.yml` file and not any specific application out of that).  Does deleting that entire `volumes:` block help?

Comment: @DavidMaze Removing volumes didn't help.  Tried listing the contents of the directory `docker-compose run api ls /usr/src/app` and it shows `node_modules package-lock.json` files in the folder.

Answer (score 1):

Your `build: { context: }` directory is set wrong.

The image build mechanism uses a *build context* to send files to the Docker daemon.  The `dockerfile:` location is relative to this directory; within the Dockerfile, the left-hand side of any `COPY` (or `ADD`) directives is always interpreted as relative to this directory (even if it looks like an absolute path; and you can't step out of this directory with `..`).

For the setup you show, where you have multiple self-contained applications, the easiest thing is to set `context:` to the directory containing the application.

```yaml
build:
  context: api
  dockerfile: Dockerfile  # the default value
```

Or, if you are using the default value for `dockerfile`, an equivalent shorthand

```yaml
build: api
```

You need to set the build context to a parent directory if you need to share files between images (see [How to include files outside of Docker's build context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27068596/how-to-include-files-outside-of-dockers-build-context)).  In this case, all of the `COPY` instructions need to be qualified with the subdirectory in the combined source tree.

```sh
# Dockerfile, when context: .
COPY api/package*.json ./
RUN npm ci
COPY api/ ./
```

You should not normally need the `volumes:` you show.  These have the core effect of (1) replacing the application in the image with whatever's on the local system, which could be totally different, and then (2) replacing *its* `node_modules` directory with a Docker anonymous volume, which will never be updated to reflect changes in the `package.json` file.  In this particular setup you also need to be very careful that the volume mappings match the filesystem layout.  I would recommend removing the `volumes:` block here; use a local Node for day-to-day development, maybe configuring it to point at the Docker-hosted database.

If you also remove things that are set in the Dockerfile (`command:`) and things Compose can provide reasonable defaults for (`image:`, `container_name:`, `networks:`) you could reduce the `docker-compose.yml` file to:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  api:          # without volumes:, networks:, image:, command:
    build: api  # shorthand corrected directory-only form
    ports:
      - '4000:4000'
    depends_on:
      - mysql
  mysql:        # without container_name:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: api
      MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 12345
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    volumes:
      - api_db:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:
  api_db:
```