# Build docker images with local npm packages

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, build

I want to be able to build images for testing purpose without publishing the changes I made in any of my packages to npm

Here is the structure of the folders:

```
/backend
  /server
    DockerFile
    package.json
  /http
    package.json
  /api
    package.json
  /dashboard
    DockerFile
    package.json
```

So each folder is a npm package (and a git repository). Here are the links between these npm packages:

- **/server** requires **/http**
- **/http** requires **/api**
- **/dashboard** requires **/api**

When I develop locally I use **npm link**, but when I want to build the docker images of **/server** and **/dashboard**, the npm links are no longer used and the packages are pulled from the published versions hosted on npm during the npm install in the container.

How can I build images based on the changes I made locally ?

I tried to link packages using a relative path in package.json :
`"my-http": "file:./../http"` instead of `"my-http": "0.1.0"`

It works locally but it's out of context when I try to build this in docker

Comment: You need to use the top-level `backend` directory as the build context (the directory option to `docker build` or Compose `build:`) and then `COPY` this entire source tree in for the relative links to work.  Also see [How to include files outside of Docker's build context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27068596/how-to-include-files-outside-of-dockers-build-context); at least one answer has a specific Typescript example.