# Copying files from a parent directory?

Tags: docker

My folder is created within a pipeline and its a transform artifact, looking like this:

```
TransformArtifact/
├─ deployment/
│  ├─ base_configs/
│  │  ├─ lambda/
│  │  │  ├─ appconfig.json
├─ lambda/
│  ├─ Dockerfile
```

Inside my dockerfile, the following line throws an error, because it references a wrong path that's later copied.

```
ARG APP_CONFIG_PATH=TransformArtifact/deployment/base_configs/lambda/
```

I've also tried `./deployment/base_configs/lambda/`, it still wouldn't work. How do I reference the `lambda` folder within my `base_configs` folder?

The full path of the Dockerfile, for example, is:
`/home/vsts/work/1/TransformArtifact/lambda/Dockerfile`. Yes, I've also tried putting the full path in front of it.

Comment: How are you building the image?  You can never `COPY` a file from outside the build-context directory; if you're trying to `COPY TransformArtifact/...` then you need to start from a parent directory, like `docker build -f TransformArtifact/lambda/Dockerfile ../`.  Also see [How to include files outside of Docker's build context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27068596/how-to-include-files-outside-of-dockers-build-context)

Comment: This is what the build command looks like

`/usr/bin/docker build -f /home/vsts/work/1/TransformArtifact/lambda/Dockerfile`

Comment: That command is missing a path argument.  Is there a `.` at the end of it?  In that directory tree, what directory are you starting from?