# Docker - How to CD into other local directory during build time

Tags: docker, dockerfile, cd

I want to `cd ..` into other directory during build time to run a command then copy what this command generated.

Question:
How to `cd` into my local machine and not on the docker image itself,
'cause `RUN cd ..` will be into it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: We cannot run scripts on the host during image creation. We would have to run the script beforehand. If we do so, we can also move the files/directories to the directory used as build context at image build time.

Comment: okk! thanks!
words to publish the comment

Comment: Are you asking [How to include files outside of Docker's build context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27068596/how-to-include-files-outside-of-dockers-build-context)

Comment: I do not, I want to copy a zip file into the container. However COPY can't find the file, am I doing something wrong with the path?