# How to copy a symlinked directory in a Dockerfile with podman

Tags: python, docker, conda, symlink, podman

I have a complex conda environment that I would like to copy into a container on build. The conda environment pre-exists and is outside the build directory hierarchy. This is the `Dockerfile` I am using:

```
FROM code.ornl.gov:4567/olcfcontainers/olcfbaseimages/mpiimage-centos-cuda

RUN mkdir /app

# conda is local symlink to conda env hierarchy outside the current working directory
COPY conda/ /app
RUN cd /app && conda activate /app/conda
```

I get the following error when building with `podman`:

```
STEP 6: COPY conda /app
Error: error building at STEP "COPY conda /app": error adding sources [/gpfs/alpine/bif135/scratch/mcoletti/deepmd_on_Summit/conda]: error reading "/gpfs/alpine/bif135/scratch/mcoletti/deepmd_on_Summit/conda": error during bulk transfer for copier.request{Request:"GET", Root:"/", preservedRoot:"/gpfs/alpine/bif135/scratch/mcoletti/deepmd_on_Summit", rootPrefix:"/gpfs/alpine/bif135/scratch/mcoletti/deepmd_on_Summit", Directory:"/", preservedDirectory:"/gpfs/alpine/bif135/scratch/mcoletti/deepmd_on_Summit", Globs:[]string{"/conda"}, preservedGlobs:[]string{"/gpfs/alpine/bif135/scratch/mcoletti/deepmd_on_Summit/conda"}, StatOptions:copier.StatOptions{CheckForArchives:false, Excludes:[]string(nil)}, GetOptions:copier.GetOptions{UIDMap:[]idtools.IDMap(nil), GIDMap:[]idtools.IDMap(nil), Excludes:[]string(nil), ExpandArchives:false, ChownDirs:(*idtools.IDPair)(0xc0004a73d0), ChmodDirs:(*os.FileMode)(nil), ChownFiles:(*idtools.IDPair)(0xc0004a73e0), ChmodFiles:(*os.FileMode)(nil), StripSetuidBit:true, StripSetgidBit:true, StripStickyBit:false, StripXattrs:false, KeepDirectoryNames:false, Rename:map[string]string(nil)}, PutOptions:copier.PutOptions{UIDMap:[]idtools.IDMap(nil), GIDMap:[]idtools.IDMap(nil), DefaultDirOwner:(*idtools.IDPair)(nil), DefaultDirMode:(*os.FileMode)(nil), ChownDirs:(*idtools.IDPair)(nil), ChmodDirs:(*os.FileMode)(nil), ChownFiles:(*idtools.IDPair)(nil), ChmodFiles:(*os.FileMode)(nil), StripXattrs:false, IgnoreXattrErrors:false, IgnoreDevices:false, NoOverwriteDirNonDir:false, Rename:map[string]string(nil)}, MkdirOptions:copier.MkdirOptions{UIDMap:[]idtools.IDMap(nil), GIDMap:[]idtools.IDMap(nil), ChownNew:(*idtools.IDPair)(nil), ChmodNew:(*os.FileMode)(nil)}}: copier: get: lstat "/conda"("/gpfs/alpine/proj-shared/chm174/conda"): lstat /gpfs/alpine/proj-shared/chm174/conda: no such file or directory
```

And, yes, that path actually exists.

Be warned that this is on the Oak Ridge National Laboratory's Summit Supercomputer, so there may also be some local weirdness.

Comment: `lstat /gpfs/alpine/proj-shared/chm174/conda` - you cannot link files from outside the build context

Answer (score 0):

The answer was gleaned from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71026394/2197955).  Since all I wanted to do was to copy in the conda env, I could set the build context in the directory that contained the conda environment while specifying the `Dockerfile`, which was in a different directory altogether.

So:

`podman build -f Dockerfile -t containertest:latest /path/to/conda/dir/ ;`