# Docker list copied files

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have command snippet like below;

```
COPY ../* ./
RUN echo "FileLogger: start"
RUN echo ls
RUN echo "FileLogger: end"
```

but this does not output files/folders copied into the target. What command I can use to list nested folders/files copied over the image?

Comment: What *does* it output? How does the output differ from what you expect?

Comment: You can't `COPY ../...` into an image from outside the build-context directory; [How to include files outside of Docker's build context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27068596/how-to-include-files-outside-of-dockers-build-context)  Is there anything in the _current_ directory besides the `Dockerfile`?  Do you mean to `RUN ls` and not `RUN echo ...` in the third line?

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove `*` from `COPY` command.

`COPY ../ ./`

And if you want to list sub-folder structure, I would suggest to use `ls -laRt`