# Shared python codebase available as a local dependency across multiple apps (docker images/containers)

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

This may be a duplicate of [How to include files outside of Docker's build context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27068596/how-to-include-files-outside-of-dockers-build-context) but...

I am looking to have a shared python codebase available as a local dependency across multiple apps (docker images/containers).

The directory structure looks like:

```
my-projects/
   |-projectlib/
   |   |-__init__.py
   |   |-utils.py
   |
   |-my-app-1/
   |   |-app.py 
   |   |-Dockerfile
   |   |-docker-compose.yaml
   |
   |-my-app-2/
       |-app.py 
       |-Dockerfile
       |-docker-compose.yaml
```

I'd like both `app.py`'s to "have" projectlib available to them inside the docker image. That is, when I call `docker compose build` inside `my-app-1` I want it to build as though the build context is:

```
|-my-app-1/
   |-app.py 
   |-Dockerfile
   |-docker-compose.yaml
   |projectlib/
      |-__init__.py
      |-utils.py
```

This is because within `app.py` I have

`from projectlib.utils import connect_to_db`

Etc..

## Why? For a few reasons:

1. I make changes to `projectlib` multiple times per day. I don't want to have one copy in each my-app-* folder for fear that they may get out of sync.
2. Ideally the `projectlib/` folder would be mapped/mounted to the containers - so that when I edit the `utils.py` file it gets "hot-reloaded" by the `app.py` files that are currently running (these are streamlit & fastApi apps).

> Note that this is all for my dev process. I'm not insane - however funny the idea of all the apps simultaneously crashing if I save the `utils.py` file with a syntax error, the deployment process is separate

## Some alternatives:

1. I could copy `projectlib/` into the build context via a bash script that then calls `docker compose build`

Is this something that can be done?

Comment: Try adding python tags as it's as much a python question as a docker one, I'm in a similar position

Comment: This would be super useful. Upvoting.

Comment: Added the tag as requested.