# Need to access test project in docker file (which is in src project)

Tags: linux, bash, docker, shell, dockerfile

I need to access the test project which is in the same solution but the docker file is in src project and inside the docker file I need to run test cases.

[image: 1]

```
#############
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

COPY ../test .
RUN ls

## Copy the applications .csproj
COPY /*.csproj .
COPY . /app
RUN ls

## Restore packages
RUN dotnet restore "./src/src.csproj" -s "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json"

## Copy everything else
COPY. /app
RUN ls
```

getting error **ERROR: "/test" not found: not found**

Comment: What artifacts do the tests produce that are required to eventually run the program?  Would it work to run the tests locally before building an image?

Answer (score 0):

Docker can access only file under the so mamed **context folder** subtree.

That folder is passed as the last parameter to the `docker build` command.

Inside the `Dockerfile` you can use only path relative to context folder and NO absolute/root paths.

This is a Docker by design constraint.

Comment: Do you think this is a duplicate of [How to include files outside of Docker's build context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27068596/how-to-include-files-outside-of-dockers-build-context)