# How to COPY host folder inside devcontainer's Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, dockerfile, vscode-devcontainer, devcontainer

I have repo A with .devcontainer, but A depends on repo B, so I want to COPY B into A's devcontainer during build (Dockerfile) to build B before A's decvontainer starts.

Moreover, I don't want to hardcode host path to B into Dockerfile, so I tried to use environment variable, but it appears to be that VSCode don't see my host env `PATH_TO_B` (I specified it using `export` command inside `~/.zshrc` and restarted terminal before starting vscode).

There is part of A devcontainer's Dockerfile I use to check if VSCode can see host env:

```
ARG PATH_TO_B
ENV PATH_TO_B=$PATH_TO_B
RUN echo "export ${PATH_TO_B}" >> /home/user/.bashrc
```

Inside running container `.bashrc` contains empty export line, which means that VSCode don't see my host's `PATH_TO_B` env variable.

Moreover, I found out that I can't do it even with hardcoding my path: VSCode devcontainer's Dockerfile can't see anything outside .devcontainer directory (so neither `../` nor absolute paths work).

Is it intended behavior or bug? How can I achieve my first goal (copy local folder into devcontainer without hardcoding path)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to include files outside of Docker's build context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27068596/how-to-include-files-outside-of-dockers-build-context)